# Grids get empty when I click on some other tab

Tags: vb.net

I have a question, I have a combo box, which when changed fills the data grid. Now Wen I change the Tab and come back to same tab again(one containing the combo box)..the value of combo box remains there, however the grid gets empty. I need this data to be maintained till the user selects another value from drop down.How can this be done???

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you got some code to show us? Would get you an answer quicker

Comment: If we shall help you, we'll need your code and we need to know how you're filling that grid.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the possible reasons :

- There is a MyDataGrid.clear somewhere
- The DataSource used to fill the grid is somewhere cleared.
- If you use a DataSet, your DataTable is somewhere truncated.
- If you use a BindingSource as your DataSource, maybe somewhere else you're using the same BindingSource, which empties the grid.

I would recommend you to put a braekpoint on your Combobox change value event to see if it's not called with a wrong value somewhere else.
And I would add a spy to check your DataGrid (the number of lines for example) to precisely know where it happens by executing my code step by step.

Hope this helps !